# How does the `TaggedTransactionQueue` runtime API know what parts of the encoded call to check?

Tags: transactions, signed-extensions

The transaction pool regularly calls the `validate_unsigned` function of the [`SignedExtension`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_runtime/traits/trait.SignedExtension.html#) trait to check transaction validity against current state. This trait then gets used to implement custom extensions in [`frame_system`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_system/index.html#signed-extensions), which get passed into the runtime as a single type, for example in a typical `runtime/src/lib.rs` file we have:

```rust
pub type SignedExtra = (
    frame_system::CheckNonZeroSender<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckSpecVersion<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckTxVersion<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckGenesis<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckEra<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckNonce<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckWeight<Runtime>,
    pallet_transaction_payment::ChargeTransactionPayment<Runtime>,
);
```

So, IIUC this then is used to construct all parts of `extra` data that a signed call submitted to the runtime expects:

```rust
/// Unchecked extrinsic type as expected by this runtime.
pub type UncheckedExtrinsic = generic::UncheckedExtrinsic<Address, Call, Signature, SignedExtra>;
```

Then, the [`TaggedTransactionQueue`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_transaction_pool/runtime_api/trait.TaggedTransactionQueue.html) runtime API provides a way to check that a submitted signed transaction is valid, giving the pool to order transaction by priority etc.

From what I understand, this runtime API verifies all the data in `SignedExtra`. My question is how?

How does this extra data gets passed into the signed extension and how does the transaction pool know what and where to check in the encoded call?

Answer (score 2):

Per my understanding,

The transaction pool doesn't know much about the extrinsics, pretty much they are opaque for the pool. But the runtime comes to save the day. `TaggedTransactionQueue` runtime API will end up calling to `pallet_executive`, which will take care of [orchestrating the whole validation](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/252156d9006ee45eda09ab80f687c066f2f4eaac/frame/executive/src/lib.rs#L615). - impl of [`TaggedTransactionQueue`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/252156d9006ee45eda09ab80f687c066f2f4eaac/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L2111-L2119) for a runtime.

`Extra` is part of the extrinsic itself already, from the beginning - [`UncheckedExtrinsic`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/252156d9006ee45eda09ab80f687c066f2f4eaac/primitives/runtime/src/generic/unchecked_extrinsic.rs#L46-L56).

As you very well mention the node will call into the runtime to to perform the necessary checks and validations for the extrinsics. Being one of the first operations checking the extrinsic  - [impl for `UncheckedExtrinsic`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/252156d9006ee45eda09ab80f687c066f2f4eaac/primitives/runtime/src/generic/unchecked_extrinsic.rs#L139).

After that the relevant `dispatch_info` will be retrieved and eventually the, now `CheckedExtrinsic`, will be validated - impl for [`CheckedExtrinsic`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/252156d9006ee45eda09ab80f687c066f2f4eaac/primitives/runtime/src/generic/checked_extrinsic.rs#L52-L67), and here is where those `SignedExtension`s from `Extra` are validated.

The source of the steps I have described can be found [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/252156d9006ee45eda09ab80f687c066f2f4eaac/frame/executive/src/lib.rs#L615).
And, for reference, you can see here how an Extrinsic is built, embedding `Extra` in it - [build()](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/252156d9006ee45eda09ab80f687c066f2f4eaac/test-utils/runtime/src/extrinsic.rs#L191)

I don't know if this will actually solve your questions or maybe it was to broad.

EDIT: Adding a clarification